# Save image with new name

Tags: ui-automation, webpage-screenshot, rpa, uipath

Anybody know how can save screenshot with new name in UiPath
My cases:

- I Have 400K url in excel and
- Open web browser >> this is ok
- Take screenshot  >> this is ok (each url)

But i do not Save this screenshot in folder as a new name.

Answer (score 0):

If you've used a **TakeScreenshot** Activity to take a screen shot means, as well you can use a **SaveImage** Activity to save your screen shot into your preferred path with *name*.

[image]